# python: multiple split violine plot overlayed

Tags: python, plotly, violin-plot

I have a set of samples to illustrate in violin plots. Here is an example by [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/violin/).

[image]

I want something similar, but multiple "blue" distributions on the left-hand side of the violin. Very likely the area under the distribution is semi-transparent and overlayed.

Is there any suggestion to plot it? It needs not to be plotly.

Thanks.

Comment: Your SO question should be self-contained. _A proper question **MUST** provide **ALL** of the information necessary in order for a proper answer to be given._ [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors, current output, expected output), as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Only images of plots are okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many traces as you want using `fig.add_trace`. Following the same example from plotly:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/violin_data.csv")

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df['day'][ df['smoker'] == 'Yes' ],
                        y=df['total_bill'][ df['smoker'] == 'Yes' ],
                        legendgroup='Yes', scalegroup='Yes', name='Yes',
                        side='negative',
                        line_color='blue')
             )
fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df['day'][ df['smoker'] == 'No' ],
                        y=df['total_bill'][ df['smoker'] == 'No' ],
                        legendgroup='No', scalegroup='No', name='No',
                        side='negative',
                        line_color='green')
             )
fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df['day'][ df['smoker'] == 'No' ],
                        y=df['total_bill'][ df['smoker'] == 'No' ],
                        legendgroup='No', scalegroup='No', name='No',
                        side='positive',
                        line_color='orange')
             )
fig.update_traces(meanline_visible=True)
fig.update_layout(violingap=0, violinmode='overlay')
fig.show()
```

Would add another trace to the left side:

[image]